# Dynamic SMTP Settings Laravel/Livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a database table for all the values that is needed for an smtp, I want to call it and change the values on the mail.php but can't I can dd(config('mail')) fine but it still gives me an error for some reason

The error

```
Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 5.7.1 Relaying denied "
```

Inside my ServiceProvider

```
// get email view data in provider class
         View::composer('*', function ($view) {
            // Get the slug from parameters
            $slug = $this->app->request->route('slug');
            if(isset($slug)){
               $configuration = ContactConfig::where("slug", $slug)->first();
               if (!is_null($configuration)) {
                $config = array(
                'driver'  =>     $configuration->driver,
                'host'       =>     $configuration->host,
                'port'       =>     $configuration->port,
                'username'   =>     $configuration->user_name,
                'password'   =>     $configuration->password,
                'encryption' =>     $configuration->encryption,
                'from'       =>     array('address' => $configuration->sender_email, 'name' => $configuration->sender_name),
                );
                   Config::set('mail', $config);
                   return;
               }
            };
            if(isset(Auth::user()->id)) {
                $configuration = ContactConfig::where("user_id", Auth::user()->id)->first();
                if(!is_null($configuration)) {
                    $config = array(
                        'driver'     =>     $configuration->driver,
                        'host'       =>     $configuration->host,
                        'port'       =>     $configuration->port,
                        'username'   =>     $configuration->user_name,
                        'password'   =>     $configuration->password,
                        'encryption' =>     $configuration->encryption,
                        'from'       =>     array('address' => $configuration->sender_email, 'name' => $configuration->sender_name),
                        'sendmail'   => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
                        'pretend' => false,
                        );
                        \Config::set('mail', $config);
                    }
                }
            });
```

I followed 2 questions that give the same answers but for some reason it doesn't not work for me, I removed the configurations on my .env file but it's stated that it should'nt be needed and I wanted to test if the dynamic settings works.

Comment: Assuming your mailer is `smtp` in any case, you should update `mail.mailers.smtp` and not the root of `mail`. Refer to how **config/mail.php** is structured

Comment: I tried to copy the mail.php but still gives me the error I even compared it side by side. I even tried hard coding my details inside the serviceprovider but gives me the same error

Comment: It seems the problem is that on the serviceprovider I change the config to theh database details but on the component it doesnt change it still gets the details from the .env

Answer (score 0):

The approach that I went with is directly changing the config in my Livewire Component I just put the Config::set() function inside the sendEmail() function before using the function Mail::to()